# HttpContext.Current.Response inside a static method

Tags: c#, static-methods, httpcontext

I have the following static method inside a static class. My question is it safe to use HttpContext.Current.Response inside a static method? I want to be 100% sure that it is thread safe and is only associated with the calling thread.. Does anybody know the answer?

```
    public static void SetCookie(string cookieName, string cookieVal, System.TimeSpan ts)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = 
                new HttpCookie(CookiePrefix + cookieName) 
                    {Value = cookieVal, Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(ts)};
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes its quite safe.  HttContext.Current will acquire the current HttpContext from the thread that is executing.

Its a common technique and saves you from having to pass the context object around like "Tramp data".

Comment: Excellent, thought so... I did not want to pass the context around all my methods.

Answer (score 14):

HTTPContext.Current is static, so the fact that you're calling it from a static method is irrelevant. What is relevant is that HTTPContext.Current is implemented in such a way that it returns the *current thread's* HTTP Context, if it exists.

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear what do you exactly mean by thread-safety. Yes, `HttpContext.Current` returns the `HttpContext` object associated with the current thread. Note that if you call the function on a thread except the one currently processing the request (for example, in an async function call), you wouldn't be able to access the `HttpContext` object you want.

Another approach is to have the context object passed as an argument to your function.