# w-s in .aspx (code-behind) tries to set cookie but can't?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, http, cookies

I have a web-service, 'AHandyWebService' implemented within a .aspx (**not** within the .aspx.cs).

I'm trying to set a cookie on the client when the web-service is called.

I'm not sure whether this is just intrinsically impossible or whether it's something to do with the way I've done it.

Because the method implementing the w-s is static I've had to implement a local instance of 'page' which I'm not sure is quite as it should be.

Method looks like this :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public static SomeObj AHandyWebService()
{
    SomeObj mySomeObj;
    try
    {
        mySomeObj = getSomeObj();
        System.Web.UI.Page p = new Page();
        HttpCookie appCookie = new HttpCookie("FOOAPP");
        appCookie.Value = String.Format("Written: {0:yyyy-MM-dd}", System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
        appCookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(1);
        appCookie.Path = "/FOO";
        p.Response.Cookies.Add(appCookie);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return mySomeObj;

}
```

By the way there are no cross-domain issues here - the w-s is provided from the same domain as the w-s consuming page was served from.

Would welcome suggestions/comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is a bit embarrassing. After a lot of trying different things I discovered the method supporting the w-s was not in fact the method I thought it was ! ... hence no cookie served !

Meanwhile in other news I came across this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728175/httpcontext-current-response-inside-a-static-method) which provided what seemed to me a more sane method of getting around accessing the Response object from a static method and so I have implemented that and it now works as it should.

In case it's of some use here's a copy of the now working method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public static SomeObj AHandyWebService()
{

    SomeObj mySomeObj;

    try
    {
        mySomeObj = getSomeObj();
        HttpCookie appCookie = new HttpCookie("FOOAPP");
        appCookie.Value = String.Format("Written: {0:yyyy-MM-dd}", System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime());
        appCookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(1);
        appCookie.Path = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(appCookie);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return mySomeObj;
}
```