# Accessing httpcontext in shared function thread safe?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, thread-safety

Im having a problem understanding if accessing httpcontext inside a shared function, without passing in the httpcontext as a parameter is thread safe?

My questions is: Are the 2 functions in the util class equally thread safe?

```
Class foo
    Sub main()
       Dim qs1 = util.getQS(HttpContext.Current)
       Dim qs2 = util.getQS()
    End Sub
End Class

Class util
    Shared Function getQS(hc As HttpContext) As String
        Return hc.Request.QueryString.ToString
    End Function
    Shared Function getQS() As String
        Return HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.ToString
    End Function
End Class
```

**EDIT** 
I found a SO post that i missed in my initial research, which also have some good answers.
For the interested:
[HttpContext.Current.Response inside a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728175/httpcontext-current-response-inside-a-static-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two functions in the question are equivalent in terms of thread safety.

Although `HttpContext` is not thread safe, getting a reference to `HttpContext.Current` is thread safe. Normally the lack of thread safety on the per-request `HttpContext` object is not an issue, because only one thread at a time processes a given request.

However, it can become an issue if you have background worker threads, etc, that are referencing the `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: Thanks @RickNZ - where could these background worker threads originate from? IIS ?

Comment: If you store `HttpContext` into a static variable, then it can become visible to IIS threads (not good). Background threads are ones that you create directly with `new Thread()` or use indirectly via a ThreadPool of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. See this question and its answers for more detail: [Using an HTTPContext across threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734821/using-an-httpcontext-across-threads)